# How to set jenkins build number in artifact name

Tags: java, jenkins

Currently my artifact is looking like this: project-1.1.jar

What I want is to add the Jenkins build number in order to look like this: project-1.1.45.jar where 45 is the build number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<project //

<name>project</name>
<version>1.1</version>

    <build>

            <finalName>${project.name}##${project.version}.${BUILD_NUMBER}</finalName>
    </build>

</project
```

buildNumber will be set to jenkins build number

Edit:I don't have access to Jenkins configuration, for me it works with ${buildNumber} instead of ${BUILD_NUMBER}.

Comment: I get null for buildNumber. Are there any Jenkins configurations needed ?

Comment: This should happen only if you build locally, not if you build on Jenkins server

Comment: aha, probably different jenkins configurations then. I will edit the answer to match this :)